# Sample function doesn't work well with purrr::rerun and pipe?

Tags: r, purrr, magrittr

I observed some weird behavior in purrr::rerun when it's used with `%>%` that I couldn't understand.

If I run,

```r
library(purrr)
sample(1:30, 3) %>% rerun(4, .)
```

it will return,

```
# 1 24 5
# 1 24 5
# 1 24 5
# 1 24 5
```

clearly it's not what I want.

However, if I run a similar code without `%>%`, it will actually work as expected.

```r
rerun(4, sample(1:30, 3))
```

```
# 17 5 20
# 13 3 6
# 22 25 3
# 20 30 29
```

I couldn't understand why the behavior is different. Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please always use a fixed random seed when providing random sample data (i.e. use `set.seed`). Otherwise we cannot reproduce your sample data and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`magrittr` doesn't evaluate the dots lazily. It might very well have, as in this mock pipe (don't use it it will break easily!)

```r
`%foo>%` <- function(e1,e2){
  eval.parent(eval(substitute(substitute(e2,list(. = substitute(e1))))))
}

sample(1:30, 3) %foo>% purrr::rerun(4, .)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 22 25  9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 14 28 21
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  4  1 25
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 17  2 25
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It is a design choice, probably made to avoid ambiguities and inefficiency when several dots are used.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which the functions are called is important. In the first case, you are selecting 3 elements from 30 and calling it 4 times. It is like doing

```
temp <- sample(1:30, 3)
purrr::rerun(4, temp)
```

So irrespective if you call it 4 times or 1000 times, the value of `temp` does not change.

Whereas in second case you are calling `sample(1:30, 3)` 4 times which gives you different results every time.